# Looping through two gridviews vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm looking for the result of comparing two aspxgridviews.

For example:
1st Gridview
1
2
3

2nd Gridview
1
2
3
4
5

I want the the output to be 4 5 in my listbox.

Here's my code so far:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To DataGridView.VisibleRowCount - 1

    For j As Integer = 0 To ExcelGridView.VisibleRowCount - 1

        If DataGridView.GetRowValues(k, "Column1").Equals(ExcelGridView.GetRowValues(j, "F2")) Then

        Else

            ResultMemo.Text = DataGridView.GetRowValues(k, "Column1")

            ListBox1.Items.Add(ResultMemo.Text)

            Exit For

        End If

    Next j

Next k
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView = 2nd Gridview 1 2 3 4 5 
ExcelGridView = 1st Gridview 1 2 3

By your style will be like this:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To DataGridView.VisibleRowCount - 1 
    dim isNotFound = true
    For j As Integer = 0 To ExcelGridView.VisibleRowCount - 1 
        If DataGridView.GetRowValues(k, "Column1")=(ExcelGridView.GetRowValues(j, "F2") Then 
            isNotFound = false
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next For
    If isNotFound then
        dim forAdd = DataGridView.GetRowValues(k, "Column1") 
        ResultMemo.Text = forAdd 
        ListBox1.Items.Add(forAdd) 
    End If
Next For
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pavel! Worked like a sharm! Many thanks my friend.